# MySQL Aggregate data by 10 days

Tags: mysql, aggregation

In MySQL, let's say I need to aggregate every 10 days' data for a certain period of time, e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(imps) FROM impressions i WHERE i.date BETWEEN SUBDATE('2014-11-10', 9) AND '2014-11-10'
UNION ALL 
SELECT SUM(imps) FROM impressions i WHERE i.date BETWEEN SUBDATE('2014-11-08', 9) AND '2014-11-08'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(imps) FROM impressions i WHERE i.date BETWEEN SUBDATE('2014-11-07', 9) AND '2014-11-07'
....
;
```

Imagine I need to do this for a month or even longer period, there will be a lot of `UNION ALL`'s.

I understand this can be achieve by using a loop in a stored procedure, but is there a way to do this without using a stored procedure? I.e can `GROUP BY` clause do the trick?

Thanks!

Sample data for table impressions:
    Date        Imps
    2014-11-10  10
    2014-11-09  15
    2014-11-08  7
    ...

Comment: Provide some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the results in columns and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(case when i.date BETWEEN SUBDATE('2014-11-10', 9) AND '2014-11-10' then imps else 0 end),
       SUM(case when i.date BETWEEN SUBDATE('2014-11-08', 9) AND '2014-11-08' then imps else 0 end),
       SUM(case when i.date BETWEEN SUBDATE('2014-11-07', 9) AND '2014-11-07' then imps else 0 end)    
FROM impressions i;
```

If you want them in different rows, then you can use a `join`, but you need a table of values:

```
SELECT SUM(case when i.date BETWEEN SUBDATE('2014-11-10', 9 + n.n) AND '2014-11-10' - interval n.n day
                then imps else 0 end)
FROM impressions i CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 0 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2
     ) n
```

Comment: Both of the methods are very clever! Thank you very much!